# Should HDDs be wiped out periodically to refresh them?

Tags: hard-drive, formatting, wipe

Should HDDs be wiped out periodically to refresh them, using Darik's Boot and Nuke for example or just when extremely needed? In other words, do programs like DBAN act like fresheners or should their use be kept at a minimum, only when needed?

I have an external laptop disk that I want to put in the place of my dying disk and wonder if I should use DBAN to make a fresh start despite the long time it takes or just 'clean' it using disk partition in cmd and perhaps chkdsk too before Windows installation.
Thank you.

Comment: What leads you to believe that you would need anything other than clearing the partitioning information? [other than for secrecy, when giving away the drive etc] I'm puzzled enough by people's insistence that Windows needs to be reinstalled every 6 months, let alone that the drive needs any kind of 'polishing' to do it.

Comment: @Tetsujin , the reinstallation myth was born with people for which it actually wasn't a myth - people who tested, installed, and uninstalled lots of softwares often not too compatible with one another. Their systems really degraded over time until a full system reinstallation was advisable. Even today, tools like CCleaner will find "orphan" leftovers in the registry from too cavalier uninstalls. While such things are minor and are now mostly harmless, previous versions of Windows were way less tolerant.

Comment: The registry was designed to have orphan keys.  There is absolutely no impact on performance.  Registry cleaners like CCleaner is the software equivalent of snake oil

Comment: @Ramhound, CCleaner is way too aggressive. It destroys stuff many users might (would?) find useful. Absolute garbage, and I won't let it anywhere near my computer.

Comment: @BillOertell - I have only used a registry cleaner once in my entire lifetime, and that because it was helpful to remove the keys from a software package, which did a poor job of cleanup after itself when it was removed.  It would refuse to install if those keys were installed.  Long story short the program was a pain in the butt and I spent most of my working day just installing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Should HDDs be wiped out periodically to refresh them?

**No**.

This varies slightly depending on drive technologies, but writing to storage devices either has no significant effects, or it may have a small detrimental effect (mostly wear and tear, especially for SSDs/SSHDs). Whatever one might want to achieve through "refreshing", there are better ways of achieving the same results.

Nuking the disk and reinstalling an **updated** image (that is: image, nuke, restore) has the only effect of increasing wear and tear, and incidentally testing (most of) the disk itself when it is read and, unnecessarily, when it is rewritten. Such testing can be done faster, more easily and more thoroughly using SMART monitoring tools. If you really want to go the "read and write back" way, the fastest tool is the [free Seagate Tools (not only for Seagate disks)](https://www.seagate.com/it/it/support/downloads/seatools/), or you can boot a Linux live distribution and run `badblocks`. I think there might be preprogrammed distros that do just that.

Modern hard disks in good condition do not significantly suffer from surface demagnetisation ("bit rot"), and if they do, you have other and more urgent problems to tackle than refreshing the hard disk, which would only temporarily assuage the symptoms. To monitor this kind of situation - electromagnetically disturbed zone, radioactive server room etc. - you use the SMART "full" or "extensive" test, which effectively reads the whole disk, rewrites where necessary, and notifies of unreliable sectors. In most cases this also "remaps" unreliable sectors so that a new reliable sector with the old content is made transparently available to the system. You need to keep track of the SMART parameters to know when the disk is in need of replacement.

If you're referring to a backup and full restore, this has the only effect of defragmenting the disk (since the files are restored one by one sequentially on an empty drive), and can be therefore done more quickly and just as effectively with the standard defragmentation tool (except perhaps when the disk is more than 90% full; in that case, a backup/restore might take four or five hours, and a full defragment a couple of days. Been there, done that). But during the defragment the system is reasonably useable, during restore it is not, so it much depends on whether you can afford the downtime.

If you're talking of a *reinstallation*, it's a very different matter and is usually markedly beneficial to performances, reducing registry clutter and ensuring there are as few software conflicts as possible (this is becoming less and less necessary, as operating systems become better at keeping track of conflicts. Of course, the less software you install/uninstall, the less need you have of straightening out the system). Unfortunately, *after* doing this it's usually necessary to also perform all system updates issued since the image was first taken. You don't do any of this with DBAN though, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

Curious, where you got the idea HD's can actually be "refreshed"?
Spinning media is not perfect and has defects causing the "bits" (i.e., "1" and "0") to either fade or disappear, sectors can over time become "bad" (i.e., problematic and inconsistent) with data unreadable and need to be removed from use...
Personally, I use/recommend SpinRite which might be the drive tool you're looking for...and resolve your "bit rot" issue(s).
[HOW does SpinRite work?](https://www.grc.com/sr/whatitdoes.htm)

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Sheez! SpinRite is still around?! I used that many years ago on a really old MFM drive. It restored that drive.